# Define variables to HTMLObjects

Tags: javascript, variables, object

When I want to add variables to an html object in Javascript, I have two possible ways;
I can use the data-x="" attribute, or I can add a variable directly to the object, right?
What's better?

For example:

obj = document.getElementById("x")

Is it valid Javascript when I define a variable like this?:

```
obj = document.getElementById("obj");
//from the data attribute
data = obj.getAttribute("data-x");
//directly
obj.data = "test";
data = obj.data;
```

What is the most correct here?
Thank you.

Comment: The best approach is not to use data attributes to begin with, you already have a reference to the object - store your application data in your application - not in your presentation layer. I'd do something like: `var myModel = {data:"test",elem:document.getElementById("obj")}` and then in subsequent code access the actual data I have for the object like that. This way you have an actual backing data model for the object - rather than storing additional information on your presentation.

Comment: I believe you can store data from JavaScript however you like (but be careful about colliding with potential new attributes). But if you want to be able to pass data from the HTML to the JavaScript, you need to use the `data-` form. Having said that, I would always store it as a `data-` attribute anyway, for consistency and future-safety.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that approach is not always practical. Recently I had a situation where I was writing an API which drew 3D content into canvases, and to avoid recreating the shaders, etc. each time I stored them in a property of the canvas. If I had stored them in an internal array with their extra data, I would have caused memory bloat / psuedo-leaks (each new canvas is added, but there is no way to know when to remove them)

Comment: Thank you, that could be answers as well. 
But when i need many variables... for example 10... i have to write down 10 different data-x attributes... its a bit dirty code, isnt it?

Comment: @T_01 Yes, for 10 variables that's _very dirty_ code - have a backing data model for storing facts that are not related to the view - like in the code example I have above. If you'd like I can add that as an answer.

Comment: @T_01 use an array or object with all the variables in, and add that as a single attribute on the object.

Comment: well, I find for larger projects avoiding associating variables directly with html objects altogether is preferable - because it can be hard to keep track of everything... it can get messy. That is, its good to separate your visual elements from you logic code. That said, on small/medium projects using an attribute is probably the preferred way. Adding a variable directly to the object (which is called an expando property) is usually considered worse practice.

Comment: @Dave Storing view data is a (and the only) legitimate use case (that is, data that is strictly _about_ the presentation of the document - like information about how to present the canvas) - that said, I'm not sure storing them in an array wouldn't have been faster in practice and have taken less space - at least in modern browsers that actually use "C arrays" for arrays when possible like Chrome.

Comment: could you come to an agreement, please :D

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum fair enough, but we don't know how the OP is using this data; they may have a similar situation. I'm inclined to believe that yours is more likely to be the correct answer though.

Comment: @T_01 the most correct out of the choices you listed would be the `attribute` version. The most correct in general is likely Benjamin Gruenbaum's suggestion of an array of objects & properties which lives in the JavaScript, not the DOM. But as with anything, there are trade-offs, so try to understand all options and choose the best for your situation.